# На объект сущности не могут ссылаться несколько экземпляров интерфейса IEntityChangeTracker, проблема в asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть модель книги

```
public class Book
{
    // id книги
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // название книги
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // автор книги
    public string Author { get; set; }
    // описаниек книги
    public string Description { get; set; }
    // жанр книги
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    // забронирована/не забронирована
    public BookState BookState { get; set; }
    // обложка книги
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    // клиент
    public string Client { get; set; }
}
```

Модель состояния книги

```
    public enum BookState
{
    // книга свободна
    Free = 0,
    // книга забронирована
    Booked = 1,
    // книга выдана
    Issued = 2
}
```

И модель бронирования книги, для ведения учета книг в "библиотеке"

```
public class Booking
{
    public int BookingId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReserveAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AcceptedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Использую систему Identity.
Проблема такова, что есть некий Task который отвечает за бронирование книги:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Reservation(int id)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
        var book = db.Books.Find(id);

        if(book.BookState == BookState.Free)
        {
            book.BookState = BookState.Booked;

            db.Bookings.Add(new Booking
            {
                Book = book,
                User = user,
                ReserveAt = DateTime.Now
            });
               db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Catalog");
    }
```

Как видно,он находит юзура по имени, книгу по id и проверяет состояние книги, после чего книга меняет свое состояние (BookState) и делает запись в таблицу Booking. Но при попытке сделать запись, выходит ошибка  - *На объект сущности не могут ссылаться несколько экземпляров интерфейса IEntityChangeTracker* из-за которой дальнейшая работа просто невозможно. Подскажите, что делать в данной ситцуации? Знаю, есть похожие вопросы на ruStackOverflow однако они мне никак не помогли. В проекте использовался подход CodeFirst.

Comment: а где `SaveChanges()`?

Comment: @4per Исправил, добавил в метод `db.SaveChanges();` но ничего не изменилось :С

Comment: вы получили юзера из одного контекста, а пишете его в другой контекст. Вы либо в другом заново юзера получите, либо этого к другому приаттачите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменил модель Booking

```
    public class Booking
    {
        public int BookingId { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
        public Book Book { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReserveAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? AcceptedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

т.е. заменил `public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }` на `public string User { get; set; }`, так же заменил в контроллере значение user, получилось в итоге так:

```
    public ActionResult Reservation(int id)
    {
        var user = User.Identity.Name;
        var book = db.Books.Find(id);

        if (book.BookState == BookState.Free)
        {
            book.BookState = BookState.Booked;

            db.Bookings.Add(new Booking
            {
                Book = book,
                User = user,
                ReserveAt = DateTime.Now
            });

            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Catalog");
    }
```